# on Low memory method and get Application class ...android

Tags: android

I am using get Application class to save some information that are used frequently in my app.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
private MYOBJECT userID;
public void getUserId(){return userId}
public MYOBJECT setUserId(int userId){this.userId=userID;}
}
```

so to be sure that the userID is not null (because low memory issue) I check in every Activity if it is equal to null if yes I restart the app in this way:

```
public class otherClass extends Activity{
@override
onCreate(bundle savedInstance){
checkUserId()...
}
     void checkUserId(){
    if (userID == null){restart the applicaton}
    }
}
```

so should I use onLowMemory() method in MainApp class instead of doing that !

Comment: `to be sure that the userID is not null` ??? what ??? userID is int ... it cannot be null ...  `(because low memory issue)` what "low memory issue" ?

Comment: sorry, actually I also use objects but for simplicity I just use int, I mean sometimes the app delete the object content so I should check first if the object equal to null and then continue ...I edit it

Comment: ... i'm pretty sure that whole app is killed ... and next time new instance of Application class is created(and onCreate is called)

Comment: actually I don't use onCreate in the application class, I set this information in other activities, is this right ?